# what is the best practice to make a field as Read-only among Page layouts Vs Field level security

Tags: profile, page-layout, field-level-security

what is the best practice to make a field as Read-only among Page layouts Vs Field level security.I'm bit confuse on this,please help us here.

Answer (score 4):

It is safer to make the field read-only via field-level security. This prevents that user from updating the field at all -- including Data Loader, Visualforce, anonymous Apex, etc. None of these would be secured if the field is read-only at the page layout level. This is the best practice. Generally it is not useful to make fields read-only on the page layout, unless there is a UI-specific reason to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Set the field to Read only at Field Level Security level. It will make field read only for that particular profile irrespective of page layout.

Answer (score 0):

**Read only on page layout**

User will not be able to see the field on edit page. field will be read only on detail page but can make change to it using anonymous window

**Read only on FLS**

User will not be able to update the field from anonymous window as well as from the edit page